# Overflow visible without adding to page width (scrollbar)

Tags: html, css

I have some elements that escape outside a containing element (they would be clipped if `overflow: hidden` was true). However, I set `overflow: visible` since I want them to be seen. *HOWEVER*, I don't want them to contribute to the width of the page (the same way they don't contribute to the width of the containing element) :

`page
+---------------------+
|                     |
| container           |
| +----------------+  |
| |                |  |
| | overflow child |  |
| | +-----------------------+
| | |                       |
| | |                       |
| | |                       |
| | +-----------------------+
| |                |  |
+---------------------_`

Here, I am seeing the entire page size to fit the "overflow child". Note: I am using an internal component that can't modify the page or anything outside of "container" (I can modify container).

To clarify, I want the inner overflow div to be this size, I just don't want it to force the page to grow (the same it doesn't force the parent element to grow).

Comment: why not set a specific width percent to child elemnt of container?.

Comment: I want the child to be that size, I just don't want the page growing to fit it. If the page happens to be large enough to fit, great, if not, don't expand.

Comment: could you please post your code? maybe a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the child element directly then you can place you child inside a div and set for this div

```
 max-width: 100%;
```

Comment: I've added an edit: I don't want to change the size of the child div, I just don't want it to make the page grow (just like it doesn't make the parent div grow).

Comment: But max-width:100% do this use the 100% of the parent width at max.